# How to check shell script has enough permissions to run

Tags: linux, shell, permissions, ubuntu-12.04

```
if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "root privileges to run this script"
        exit 1
fi
```

This script checks user is a root.
But my requirement is to check if a user has enough permission to run this script, rather than only checking root user.

Is any other right away to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm terribly sorry: There was a good answer by user edwardramsey on this topic, where I made a (bad, i.e. incorrect) comment on it. I wanted to delete my comment, but I ended up to delete the answer! Does anybody know, how to un-delete it?
In any case, I quote here the response provided by edwardramsey:*

To test a program, whether you have privileges to execute it, you do

```
if [ -x PROGRAM ]
then
   ...
fi
```